# Keys naming in jsonb_agg postgres function

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have sql:
`select jsonb_agg((u.id, u.name)) as user_data from users u where u.id = '1';`
and result is:

```
[
  {
    "f1": "1",
    "f2": "Robert Miles"
  }
]
```

but i want json object keys to be automapped to original names:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Robert Miles"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the whole row to `jsonb_agg`

```sql
select jsonb_agg(u) as user_data
from users u
where u.id = '1';
```

Alternatively, supply the field names explicitly using `jsonb_build_object`

```sql
select jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('id', u.id, 'name', u.name)) as user_data
from users u
where u.id = '1';
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=68007f4959500d6186cb4eeb85b21f2e)

Comment: In first example i get all fields, but i need specific fields only, in second i still need to point key names manually

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question, is this possible?

Comment: Why doesn't it answer it?